# How to validate pointer to std vector internal array

Tags: c++, stdvector

I would like to write to internal array of vector. I could write using `data()` if vector is initialised.
However if the vector is empty (but having enough storage), I am not able to write directly to internal array of vector.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void write_seq(int *v, size_t len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        v[i] = i;
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "reserve and write\n";
    v.reserve(10);
    write_seq(v.data(), v.capacity());
    cout << "seq length " << v.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out 
reserve and write
seq length 0
```

How to avoid this kind of situations, is it possible to validate `data()` pointer of vector?

Edit:
I assumed two things with this question, on an empty `vector v;`,

- `v.reserve(10)` allocates memory for 10 elements and
- `v.data()` points to that allocated memory.

Comment: `reserve` is not `resize`. `How to avoid this kind of situations` actually resize the vector.

Comment: @srabhishek The function does not change the size of the vector because it knows nothing about the vector. It deals with a raw memory.

Comment: btw I don't think "validate" is the right word. You seem to expect that writing to `v[i]` extends the size of the vector, but thats not the case, just like assigning to an out-of-bounds index in a c-array is undefined behavior

Comment: @idclev 463035818 yes, I assumed that writing to `v[i]` writes directly to the vector  storage.

Comment: it does do that. My comment was a bit sloppy. It is not "like" using a c-array, it **is** using a c-array. You are directly writing to the vectors internal storage and even though it has capacity it has 0 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to an element that does not exist. Allocating memory is not sufficient, but your code is fine when you resize the vector (or create it with sufficient elements):

```
int main(void)
{
    vector<int> v(10);                         // vector with 10 element
    write_seq(v.data(), v.size());             // write to those 10 element
    cout << "seq length " << v.size() << "\n"; // size is (still) 10 
    return 0;
}
```

Note that your code is not very idomatic. I assume you have reasons for that, but passing iterators to `write_seq` would be much more natural.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `resize`, not `reserve`, and `size` instead of `capacity`. `reserve` simply gives the vector the added capacity, without actually increasing the size. `resize` increases the size to match the reserved capacity.

Comment: I used `size()` to show that vector's internal array is not filled. Also I didn't use `resize()` because vector is empty.

Comment: @srabhishek You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding on what the difference between `size`  and `capacity` actually are.  The `capacity` is how many elements the array has been allocated to hold. The elements themselves are not guaranteed to be valid. The `size` is the number of valid elements within the `capacity`. You can't *legally* assign values to elements whose index is `>= size` even if there is `capacity` allocated for them, as they have not been constructed yet. For POD types, you can get away with this, but not for non-POD types.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to concern yourself with how much memory you need to reserve beforehand. If performance is not really an issue, you may consider instead using auto-resizable back inserting iterators to push the elements at the step you want to push them.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Iterator>
void write_seq(Iterator v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        *v = i;  // actually calls std::vector<>::push_back() internally
        v++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::cout << "just write them data!\n";
    write_seq(std::back_inserter(v));
    std::cout << "seq length " << v.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the concept of `size` and `capacity` of a vector. size is the number of elements stored while capacity is internal space allocated. capacity is always great than or equal to size.  If you insert elements into the vector and caused the vector to run out of capacity, it will automatically increase its capacity by allocating a new space twice of current capacity, then copy existing elements into the new space, then delete the old space.

If you are planning to insert a large number of elements into a vector, the "auto increasing capacity" feature is not efficient, as it will keep allocating new spaces and copying elements. Instead, you can use `reserve()` to allocate enough space beforehand, and thus to avoid the process to keep allocating new spaces.

`capacity():` Returns the number of elements that the container has currently allocated space for.

`reserve():` Increase the capacity of the vector to the given size or more.

`size():` Returns the number of elements in the container.

`resize():` Changes the number of elements stored.

---

Back to your question, you can simply replace `reserve` with `resize`:

```
int main(void)
{
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "reserve and write\n";
    v.resize(10);  // use resize() instead of reserve()
    write_seq(v.data(), v.size());
    cout << "seq length " << v.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

Or, you can insert into the vector directly:

```
void write_seq(vector<int>& v, size_t len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        v.push_back(i);  // add an element to the vector, this changes the size
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "reserve and write\n";
    v.reserve(10);  // this does not change size, the vector is still empty
    write_seq(v, v.capacity());
    cout << "seq length " << v.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: allocating twice the current capacity is common but not guaranteed. Any factor is fine as long as it is sufficient to get amortized constant complexity for `push_back`